# Angular2 wysiwyg component not posting

Tags: forms, angular, wysiwyg

I am trying to learn angular2 by building a nice wysiwyg component but it seams that I hit a brick wall right now. So, here's my code:

app.component.ts is a form I'm using for testing the component(i modified the hero-form from angular tutorial):

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {NgForm}    from 'angular2/common';
import { Article }    from './article';
import {aWysiwygComponent} from './aWysiwyg.component'

@Component({
  selector: 'test-form',
  templateUrl: 'app/article-form.component.html',
  directives: [aWysiwygComponent]
})
export class ArticleFormComponent {
  model = new Article(18, 'Dr IQ', 'Chuck Overstreet');
  submitted = false;
  onSubmit() { this.submitted = true; }
  // Reset the form with a new hero AND restore 'pristine' class state
  // by toggling 'active' flag which causes the form
  // to be removed/re-added in a tick via NgIf
  // TODO: Workaround until NgForm has a reset method (#6822)
  active = true;
  newArticle() {
    this.model = new Article(42, '', '');
    this.active = false;
    setTimeout(()=> this.active=true, 0);
  }
}
```

and the html for this is:

```
<div class="container">
  <div  [hidden]="submitted">
    <h1>Hero Form</h1>
    <form *ngIf="active" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #articleForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" required
          [(ngModel)]="model.name"
            ngControl="name"  #name="ngForm" >
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
          Name is required
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="content">Content</label>
          <aWysiwyg [(model)]="model.content"></aWysiwyg>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!articleForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="newArticle()">New Article</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <h2>You submitted the following:</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Name</div>
      <div class="col-xs-9  pull-left">{{ model.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Content</div>
      <div class="col-xs-9 pull-left">{{ model.content }}</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-default" (click)="submitted=false">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here is the wysiwyg component:

```
import {Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {ToolbarComponent} from './components/toolbar.component';
import {EditableComponent} from './components/editable.component';
import { NgForm, FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';


@Component({
    selector: 'aWysiwyg',
    templateUrl: '../app/templates/editor.html',
    styleUrls:['./app/styles/bootstrap.min.css', './app/styles/styles.css', './app/styles/font-awesome.min.css'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [ToolbarComponent, EditableComponent, FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class aWysiwygComponent {
    @Input() model:any;
 }
```

html:

```
<section class="editor col-sm-24 col-lg-24">
    <aToolbar class="row">Loading...</aToolbar>
    <aEditable [(model)]="model" class="row">Loading...</aEditable>
</section>
<textarea class="form-control" id="hiddenInput" hidden>{{model}}</textarea>
```

editable-area component:

```
import {Component, Input, AfterViewInit} from 'angular2/core';
import { NgForm, FORM_PROVIDERS, FORM_DIRECTIVES } from 'angular2/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'aEditable',
    templateUrl: './app/templates/editable.html',
    providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS],
    directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class EditableComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
    @Input() model:any;

    ngAfterViewInit(){
        jQuery('#editable-area').keyup(function(){
            jQuery('#hiddenInput').text(jQuery('#editable-area').html())
        })
    }
 }
```

and html:

```
<section id="editable">
    <div id="editable-area" contenteditable >
         {{model}}
    </div>
</section>
```

The rest of the project is just a bunch of components for the toolbar. Now, the problem is that when I submit the form I get nothing from the wysiwyg, even doe I am writing content in it and I see that content being copied into the `textarea`, it doesn't post it with the rest of the form. I checked the console and there are no exceptions, everything looks fine. Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: You need a `ControlValueAccessor` for custom elements to work with `ngModel` http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bangular2%5D+controlvalueaccessor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here.

If you want to leverage two way binding, you also need to have an `Output` in your component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'aEditable',
  templateUrl: './app/templates/editable.html',
  providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class EditableComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
  @Input() model:any;
  // The name is important here (the suffix "Change") to be
  // able to use the syntax shortcut: [(model)]
  @Output() modelChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    jQuery('#editable-area').keyup(() => {
      let content = jQuery('#editable-area').html();
      this.modelChange.emit(content);
      jQuery('#hiddenInput').text(content);
    });
  }
}
```

Moreover, your `aEditable` component is `ngModel` / `ngControl` compliant. This means that it can't take part of the form validation and its global state. If you want / need this feature, you have to implement a custom value accessor. Here is a sample in your case:

```
const EDITABLE_VALUE_ACCESSOR = new Provider(NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, { useExisting: forwardRef(() => EditableComponent), multi: true});

@Component({
  selector: 'aEditable',
  templateUrl: './app/templates/editable.html',
  providers: [FORM_PROVIDERS, EDITABLE_VALUE_ACCESSOR],
  directives: [FORM_DIRECTIVES]
})
export class EditableComponent implements ControlValueAccessor { 
  content:string;

  onChange = (_) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};

  writeValue(value: any): void {
    this.content = value;
    // write in the DOM
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(){
    jQuery('#editable-area').keyup(() => {
      this.content = jQuery('#editable-area').html();
      jQuery('#hiddenInput').text(this.content);
      this.onChange(content);
    });
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: (_: any) => void): void { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: () => void): void { this.onTouched = fn; }
}
```

To finish you could leverage Angular2 support to interact with the DOM instead of using jQuery. For example with the `@ViewChild` decorator:

```
<section #editable>
  <div id=#editableArea contenteditable >
    {{model}}
  </div>
</section>
```

And in the component

```
@ViewChild('editable')
editableElement:ElementRef;

@ViewChild('editableArea')
editableAreaElement:ElementRef;

constructor(private renderer:Renderer) {
}

onAfterViewInit() {
  (...)
}
```

This question regarding editable content could also interest you:

- [How can I use ngControl in contenteditable element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36122136/how-can-i-use-ngcontrol-in-contenteditable-element/36127916#36127916)